# State value is shown only after re-render

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

The console.log prints an empty array but If I trigger a re-render, it will print the values from the db.

Im guessing that it's logging before the initial setState?

```
  const [curse, setCurse] = useState([]);
  const usersCollectionRef = collection(db, "curse");

  useEffect(() => {
    const getUsers = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(usersCollectionRef);
      setCurse(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
      console.log(curse);
    };

    getUsers();
  }, []);
```

Comment: `setCurse` (`useState`) is asynchronous, so you cannot see the change (`console.log` after `setCurse`) until the component gets re-rendered.

Comment: And how can I make this work? Put the setState into another function?

Comment: I think you need to if(curse.length>0) condition.

Comment: The code should already be working, it's just the log statement that doesn't work because you're logging the old array. If you need to log out the new array, then assign that array to a local variable and log that. `const temp = data.docs.map(/*...*/); setCurse(temp); console.log(temp);`

Comment: please post what is `collection` and what type of data does the `await getDocs(usersCollectionRef);` return.

Comment: You can add another `useEffect` to listen to `curse` state change like this `useEffect(() => { if(curse.length > 0) { //TODO: Add your expected logic here } }, [curse])` @MariusDamian

Answer (score 0):

You can try this:

```
 useEffect(() => {
    const getUsers = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(usersCollectionRef);
      setCurse(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
      curse && console.log(curse);
    };

    getUsers();
  }, []);
```

Answer (score 0):

Per [React Docs](https://beta.reactjs.org) state [update asynchronous](https://beta.reactjs.org/apis/usestate#ive-updated-the-state-but-logging-gives-me-the-old-value) because state updates cause re-render which maybe an expensive operation. Making state updates asynchronous and batched for performance gained.

If you want to access updated state ways are:

- Access state directly inside the function component.

```
useEffect(() => {
    const getUsers = async () => {
      const data = await getDocs(usersCollectionRef);
      setCurse(data.docs.map((doc) => ({ ...doc.data(), id: doc.id })));
      console.log(curse);
    };

    getUsers();
}, [])

console.log(curse); // log or check updated state
```

- Use `useEffect` hook add your state as dependency in order to log or perform side-effect with updated state.

```
useEffect(() => {
  // do something with updated state
}, [curse])
```

- Use Mutation refs to keep a clone of state value cause ref update not cause re-render

```
const [curse, setCurse] = useState([])
const myRef = useRef(curse)

useEffect(() => {
  myRef.current = curse
}, [curse])
```